# Creating a new object from method's param

Tags: java

Let's say you got a `class` **x** with a method `copy()`.

This method `copy()` gets a `class` **y** as a param. `copy(y test)`.

My question is, how do I make a new object out of the class that's sent as param just like this:

```
public void copy(y villy){
       villy v = new villy();
    }
```

**You should consider that the** *y* **class is a parent one, and that I'll be passing as params its childs aswell, so what that method should do is creating a new object of the class that's sent as param!**

Comment: Can't do it (or at least not without some horrible reflection tricks). What if they pass in a singleton subclass, which isn't supposed to have more than one instance?

Comment: explore reflection library

Comment: How can a object become a class ?

Comment: Look, maybe this will help you understanding the situation: Look at the x class as a character, this character has a copy() ability that allows him to become the exact copy of a y charachter. This y character may change, it's not just one @resueman

Comment: We're creating Objects from a y class @PritamBanerjee

Comment: In your copy method villy is passed as an object of type y. After that villy becomes a class. How are you planning to do that ? Are you planning to generate a new class with the name of that object ?

Comment: So, I have class a class b and class c, then I've class x with the method copy().

Comment: This method should create an a,b or c object respect to the class that's sent as a parameter @PritamBanerjee

Comment: This question is good example to why we need naming conventions. If the classname was staring by an uppercase char and the parameter he would not have mixed class name and parameter name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parameter is a `Class` reference, and the class has a public constructor with no parameters:

```
public void copy(Class cls){
   Object obj = cls.newInstance();
}
```

If the parameter is some object implementing the `Cloneable` interface, and another object of the same class is required:

```
public void copy(Cloneable obj1){
   Object obj2 = obj1.clone();
}
```

**EDIT 20.01.2016**

So I assume that every object is a Pokemon, which has some abilities, and it has a method `copy` used to copy the abilities of another Pokemon. Then I would do it like this:

```
public class FET {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Pokemon aerodactyl = new Pokemon (new Ability[]{ Ability.WALK, Ability.FLY  });
        Pokemon golduck    = new Pokemon (new Ability[]{ Ability.WALK, Ability.SWIM });

        System.out.println ("aerodactyl = " + aerodactyl);
        System.out.println ("golduck    = " + golduck   );
        System.out.println ();

        golduck.copy (aerodactyl);

        System.out.println ("aerodactyl = " + aerodactyl);
        System.out.println ("golduck    = " + golduck   );      // golduck has now the same abilities as aerodactyl
        System.out.println ();

        aerodactyl.abilities[0] = Ability.EXPLODE;              // change aerodactyl's abilities

        System.out.println ("aerodactyl = " + aerodactyl);
        System.out.println ("golduck    = " + golduck   );      // abilities of aerodactyl have changed but golduck's not
        System.out.println ();

    }

}

enum Ability {
    WALK,
    FLY,
    SWIM,
    TALK,
    EXPLODE
}

class Pokemon {

    public Ability[] abilities;

    public Pokemon (Ability[] abilities) {              // constructor
        this.abilities = abilities;
    }

    public void copy (Pokemon p) {                      // copy abilities of another Pokemon
        abilities = (Ability[]) p.abilities.clone();
    }

    public String toString() {                          // string representation of Pokemon
        String str = "Pokemon";
        if (abilities != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < abilities.length; i++) {
                str += (i==0) ? ": " : ", ";
                str += abilities[i];
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

Comment: My IDE (Android Studio) makes me do something like this:                  `public void copy(Class cls) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();
    }`

Comment: Just to notify you, I mean it just adds a way to catch the exception

Comment: @FET, refer to what?

Comment: To the specific brand new object created

Comment: @FET, in the first case the new object is stored in the variable `obj`, in the second case - in `obj2`. Frankly speaking, we all here still don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. What is the overall task? Why do you need to create objects of different types in one method? Do you need the `copy` method to return the created object or to do something with it right on the spot?

Comment: I need just to copy that Object, because as I said (or if I didn't now I will): you should see it as an ability of a character, it can become another character and get all its abilties. So depending on what the user chooses to become, it should change the final object. By the way if you got something better in mind please share that 'cause I'd apreciate it!

Comment: @FET, the object you want to copy - is it a character or an ability? "It can become another character" - what does it mean?

Comment: This character is like the Pokemon "Ditto" it can assume somebody else's abilities, so basically it can become another character. This character has the ability to become another one. Like water becomes wine.

Comment: @FET, so I assume that every object is a Pokemon, which has some abilities, and it has a method `copy` used to copy the abilities of another Pokemon. I have edited my answer, please see above.